# Reading a csv file and selecting three columns in Scala

Tags: scala, data-manipulation, data-retrieval

I need to read a csv file and then to make a new file having the specified 3 columns ..
 I am aware of reading a text file but not csv file .

```
import scala.io.Source._
val lines = fromFile("file.txt").getLines
```

Comment: there is nothing magic about csv file. Split every line by `,` and take what you need...

Answer (score 1):

Or if you just want the first three columns, try this

```
val lines = fromFile("file.txt").
              getLines.
              map(_.split(",",4).take(3)).
              toList
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming a collection of indices `idx` that refer to columns in the csv file, consider first

```
val idx = Array(1,3,4)
val xs = (1 to 10).toArray
```

and so we can fetch the 2nd, 4th and 5th columns (index 0 refers to the first column),

```
idx.map(xs)
Array(2, 4, 5)
```

We can apply this idea onn each array from splitting each line as follows,

```
Source.fromFile("file.csv").getLines.map(_.split(",").map(idx))
```

This approach allows for defining the indices of interest at runtime (non hard-coding).